# Is there any algorithm to detect the two furthest node in a graph? Sorry if the question might be trivial

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm

Hi all I am searching an algorithm to determine which are the 2 furthest node in an undirected unweighted graph. So I mean only in terms of edges. For example in the photo should be the two marked in red with a distance of 4 edges.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN8D6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding longest path in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320556/finding-longest-path-in-a-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more complete result can be given thanks to the Dijkstra algorithm, which will give you the distance between each points of the graph. In [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/) simple implementation, the graph is represented as a matrix of neighborhood, and you get all the distances. You can adapt the code to not print the result in the shell but to return a matrix of distances or a dictionnary, and take the max.